# Are there any advanced options for Google Chrome's history search?

Tags: google-chrome, search

Google Chrome's history search is somewhat … less powerful than I'd like it to be.

[image]

**Examples:**

These are some annoyances I've found while trying to work with the Chrome search.

- Searching for `superuser.com` returns results from `stackoverflow.com` too.
- Searching for `site:superuser.com` does not work at all.
- `"phrase queries"` seem to work fine, but they're not indicated.
- Searching for `hashify.me` returns 3 results, none of those actually from [hashify.me](http://hashify.me/), whereas searching for `hashify` returns hundreds of URLs I visited on this site.

---

**What I need:**

- Is there any way to specify **advanced search options** there?
- Which operators or types of queries can I use to search in Google Chrome?
- If not, can I use some other method to search my history more efficiently?

The Chrome help does not mention anything related.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't with the built-in history, but maybe you could try an extension:

### [History 2](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cahejgbbfgmlmjgdjlibphdjeldhagkp)

> History 2 overrides default history page with a more user-friendly one. (Tools Menu > History or Ctrl-H)
>
> History 2: A history page like the original but grouped by the host for easy viewing.

[image]

---

### [Better History](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/better-history/egehpkpgpgooebopjihjmnpejnjafefi)

> A better look at your browsing history. The best searching, the sharpest interface, and the most useful filters - for your history.
> It's Chrome History, only much Better.

[image]

---

**EDIT:**
Another good extension you could try:

### [History Plus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mmeiidaaeapionnjaheefgcflidanoeg)

> - Select date range easier: Today, Yesterday, Last Week, Last Month, All
> - Select max result number easier: 100, 250, 500, 1000
> - Delete history
> - Grouping same domain in the list
> - Show visit counts each url in the list

[image]

Comment: These are actually pretty nice, I haven't thought of extensions yet. *Better History* seems to work better than *History 2*, although its search options are not documented. Have you used any of these?

Comment: they have not a good search option support, but history2 group every urls based on domain name, at least is a little easier to find what you need...

Comment: Yes, that's true. Definitely +1, they're very useful. *Better History* seems to be under steady development, which is nice.

Comment: added another extension

Comment: History2 isn't exactly the best, but it did help me remove all bookmarks from a certain domain. I moved from a dyndns domain to a custom domain and the damn dyndns url kept coming up in the address bar. Deleting the dyndns urls fixed this =)

Comment: @Marcx, None of these seem to search text within the webpages. Is there a solution for that?

Comment: @Pacerier whoa, I think this would be absolutely overkill. I doubt you'll find this functionality in History plugins, but good luck.

Comment: 2018: History Plus and History 2 are both dead links

Comment: All dead links. Apparently, writing a history enhancer extension is a good way to get yourself waxed.

Answer (score 6):

After trying a lot of extensions, I would recommend one.
Ladies and Gentlemen, ... the winner is

### (different) [Better History](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/better-history/egehpkpgpgooebopjihjmnpejnjafefi)

There is possibility to search using RegExp (Regular Expressions), which is the most powerful way for searching.
E.g: `/^h.*\/\/cz\./` searches for anything that:

- `^h` - begins with "h" (http, https)
- `.*` - continues with anything
- `\/\/` - continues "//"; `\` is used to escape the "/"
- `cz` - continues with "cz"
- `\.` - continues with "."; `\` escapes otherwise special-meaning `.`, which stands for "any character you might think of"

Note: `/` in the beginning and end, just enables Regular Expression search.

Image of how the Regular Expressions search works within this Extension:
[Better History Chrome Extension showing searching using Regular Expressions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TmXA.png)

Comment: The only extension not a 404 today. Are these apps getting hit by some secret privacy gestapo?

Comment: Perfect! It finds a part of the word, in distinct to that silly google search mechanism.

Comment: Link works fine today. Store shows updated 1/22.

Comment: Not searches are still too difficult especially since searches match either URL or Page Title, but better than nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Few days ago I got to know about [History Timeline](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/history-timeline/) chrome extension. It overrides actual history page and shows you history as timeline with thumbnail which helps to search particular web page. You can even filter results, refine your search by giving time period etc.

[image: History Timeline Screenshot]

Comment: That extension no longer exists. `:-/`

Comment: I found an archive copy... https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://clients2.googleusercontent.com/crx/blobs/QgAAAC6zw0qH2DJtnXe8Z7rUJP3VMlY8CT0wBpgCp36ixEfhCzkwJJZEN1nRooBjwt07UIsStvYeJ8AEFhrHgnk31IDlVWxifB-pixqPkdC_EFRYAMZSmuWEG_DFg60IivuMtbfxxAOCuYBv7w/extension_0_87.crx

Comment: linke to archive doesn't work

Comment: Better links to web.archive.org: page-[link](https://clients2.googleusercontent.com/crx/blobs/QgAAAC6zw0qH2DJtnXe8Z7rUJP3xa83im2Dn6HJ8uJ1lTwhp3ZD-6NXRVMpXHEe6XHzsm3QF648zMJ8Yx5j5uxU-k4k2uqMO7zAiKZIG5SNu5d2nAMZSmuXXA3iVqyPVb7d2WZ4TYDMvEiOaGw/extension_0_87.crx), download-[link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180624222834/https://clients2.googleusercontent.com/crx/blobs/QgAAAC6zw0qH2DJtnXe8Z7rUJP3xa83im2Dn6HJ8uJ1lTwhp3ZD-6NXRVMpXHEe6XHzsm3QF648zMJ8Yx5j5uxU-k4k2uqMO7zAiKZIG5SNu5d2nAMZSmuXXA3iVqyPVb7d2WZ4TYDMvEiOaGw/extension_0_87.crx)