# Displaying timestamp in Google Chrome browsing history

Tags: google-chrome, history, timestamp

Google Chrome allows to view the browsing history. Is there any way to display a more complete timestamp i.e. having the hour, minute and second instead of having just the date?

[image]

Comment: Hello Franck, slhck had a [similar question](http://superuser.com/questions/352970/are-there-any-advanced-options-for-google-chromes-history-search) some years ago. The 3 extensions in the [accepted answer](http://superuser.com/a/353165/50173) do what you are looking for. My personal favorite is [History Plus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/history-plus/mmeiidaaeapionnjaheefgcflidanoeg)

Comment: @nixda thanks, I installed the Google Chrome extension Better History, it works great!