# How can I search for and delete multiple entries in the Chrome history?

Tags: google-chrome, history

Chrome has a feature that lets you filter the history on chrome://history and show a subset of your history. You can then delete one and one entry. Unfortunately, there is no "Select All", which gets tedious. So I am trying to figure out how I can do this in some other way.

[image: kode24 search result]

Unfortunately, hacking this by trying to query the DOM did not get me anywhere. I can only find a single `div` on the page, and the Inspector tells me this is due to it being hidden in the shadow dom. So ... is there some way I can select all of these search hits OR through some other means delete *parts of* the history? I know I can delete *all of history* within segments of time (last hour, last day, last week, etc).

[image: shadow dom in inspector]

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately found a [related answer](https://superuser.com/a/353165/69121), leading me to the extension called [Better History](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/better-history/egehpkpgpgooebopjihjmnpejnjafefi/related), which lets you do batch deletes.